# Get next character code adding 1 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable which holds a letter. In order to have a concrete example let's assume it is 'A'. 
I have a while loop which on certain conditions will change that variable to the next letter ('B' in this case).

I would like to know how to achieve that in python:

```
Pseudocode:
char = 'A'
next_char = 'A' + 1


Python:
letter = 'A'
next_letter = 'A' + 1 # This fails with error TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the case and question is the same as the one you point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
letter = 'A'
next_letter = chr(ord(letter) + 1)
```